# How to execute code after finishing all $.getJSON calls, including inner ones, and ones in loops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I've got this code.

```
$.getJSON("/some-path.json",function(resultArray){
  for (var j = resultArray.length - 1; j >= 0; j--){
    $.getJSON(resultArray[j],function(resultObject){
      // Bunch of stuff happens here
    });
  }
}).done(function(){
  // This should execute only after ALL $.getJSON codes above finish
});
```

But the code in `.done()` runs before all the `.getJSON()` stuff finishes. How do I make the code in `.done()` execute AFTER the `.getJSON()` stuff finishes?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `async`/`await` syntax, and use `Promise.all` to wait for all of the inner fetches to complete:

```
(async () => {
  const resultArray = await $.getJSON("/some-path.json");
  await Promise.all(resultArray.map(
    url => $.getJSON(url, (innerResult) => {
      // Bunch of stuff happens here
    })
  ));
  // all inner results have completed
})();
```